# useSession returning session object as null in production nextauth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am using next auth to provide google sign up for my project and it was working fine in development but when I deployed it the session object is returning null. The env file contains all the necessary values nextauth_url,nextauth_secret,google_id, and google_secret and the redirect Uri is also set in the google console.

[...nextauth].ts

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code"
        }
      }
    }),
  ],
   callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      console.log(user.id)
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      session.user.userId = user.id;
      console.log(session.user.userId) 
      return session
    }
  },
  secret:process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET,
  debug: true,
})
```

index.tsx

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { useSession} from 'next-auth/react';
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from '../app/store';
import {addCurrentUser} from '../components/currentUserSlice'
import SignUpLoginFullScreen from '../components/SignUpLoginFullScreen';
import LoadingScreen from '../components/LoadingScreen';
import MainSection from '../components/MainSection';
import PostsList from '../components/Posts/PostsList';


const Home: NextPage = () => {
  
  const {data:session,status}=useSession();
  console.log(session,status)

  const currentUser=useSelector((state:RootState)=>state.currentUser);
  console.log(currentUser)

  const dispatch=useDispatch();

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(session?.user){
      console.log(session.user)
      dispatch(
        addCurrentUser({name:session.user.name,
                        email:session.user.email,
                        image:session.user.image,
                        userId:session?.user.userId}))
    }
     
  },[session?.user,dispatch,session?.user.userId])

  return (
  <>
       {!session && status==='loading' && 
      <LoadingScreen/>
    }
      
    {session && 
        <MainSection>
            <PostsList currUserId={currentUser.userId} errMsg='No posts found'/>
        </MainSection>
     }
      
      {!session && 
      <SignUpLoginFullScreen/>
    }

  </>
  )
}

export default Home
```